# SVN Access Forbidden to Commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, collabnet, subversion-edge

I just created the server (Collabnet Subversion Edge). The repositories, groups and logins are new. But at the first attempt to commit, a message of access denied appeared, using TortoiseSVN.

The code bellow, doesn't work, and I received "Access Forbidden" at commit:

```
######################SVN Groups###################
[groups]                                    
java:epa
delphi:epa,tmm

##############Folder-Specific-Access-Rules#########
[EXEs:/svn/EXEs]
@delphi=rw

[compD7:/svn/compD7]
@delphi=rw
tmm=rw
```

If I change the rules, allowing all repositories, it works normally. If I add this line [/], works:

```
##############Folder-Specific-Access-Rules#########
[/]
tmm=rw
epa=rw

[EXEs:/svn/EXEs]
@delphi=rw (...)
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Is there a difference between the "@" syntax and the one without?

Comment: @royalTS : @ signifies its a "group"

Comment: Can you mention what user are using to commit along with path/URL of SVN?

Comment: I'm using user "tmm"